# APIs to get the Wikipedia page category?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia-api

#### Problem

Given the title of the Wikipedia page is there an API to get what category that page belongs to.

#### Examples

- Given the page title "Battle of Hastings" API gives back "Historical Event" (or
  something along that line).
- Given the page title "Thomas Edison" API gives back "Scientist".
- Given the page title "Barack Obama" API gives back "US President".

Of course, the categories mentioned above are just an example to pass what I mean by saying "category".

Having checked the [actions possible on a query API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query) I have not found an API that gives back a specific category, however, I have noticed under [most viewed pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Multiyear_ranking_of_most_viewed_pages) rankings are based on some categories (Sportsmen, Actors etc). Unless this has been done manually (I hope not!) I'm wondering what APIs have been used to gather such information.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

See [API:Categorymembers](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categorymembers) or [tool on labs](https://petscan.wmflabs.org).

Or [SQL](https://quarry.wmflabs.org/query/28737)
(via Quarry tool or directly if you have an account [on Toolforge](https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Toolforge/Database))